# How to append Tweets with time stamp as data frame in R

Tags: r

I am using this code to extract tweets using R, I also want to append the time stamp w.r.t each tweets and store it in data frame. The time stamp in data frame should be in proper date & time format not just numbers.
Here is the code:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
library(stringr)
# Set API Keys
api_key <- ".................."
api_secret <- "..............."
access_token <- "............."
access_token_secret <- ".............."
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
# Grab latest tweets

tweets<- searchTwitter('@xyz', n=3000,lang="en",resultType="recent") 
str(tweets[[1]])
tweets[[1]]$created # date time
#tweet_text<-[]
timestamp<-0
for (tweet in length(tweets))
{ #tweet_text[tweet]<-tweets[[tweet]]$getText
  timestamp[tweet]<-tweets[[tweet]]$created
 }
```

The above code is just in the nascent stage, it did not work. What I intended to do is: Create a data frame having four columns: 1. Tweet 2. Date_time_stamp 3. Date  4. Time

Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("#AlternativeFacts", n=2)
t(sapply(tweets, function(x) 
  with(x, cbind(text, created, format(created, "%F"), format(created, "%T")))
     [,1]                                [,2]         [,3]         [,4]      
[1,] "Les #AlternativeFacts se disen..." "1485535839" "2017-01-27" "16:50:39"
[2,] "RT @funder: Trump Owns Stake I..." "1485535839" "2017-01-27" "16:50:39"
```